# Would my opponents be denied their Dex bonus if I were to target them with a spell while invisible or in stealth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If I were to cast a spell targeting an opponent while invisible or stealthed, would they be denied their Dexterity bonus? For example, if I cast Enervation while under the effect of Invisibility, would their Dex bonus be subtracted from their touch AC?

Answer (score 9):

## Yes

From [Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat):

> If you can't react to a blow, you can't use your Dexterity bonus to AC.

(Also see [Combat Modifiers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Modifiers), which explicitly states an attacker's Invisibility denies dexterity to the defender)

This means that for spells which require a touch attack, such as Enervation, they would not be able to use their dexterity bonus unless they had detected you by other means.

Note that this only applies to Armor Class; it does *not* apply to spells which require a Reflex Save, such as Fireball.

Comment: I was looking for this, but was unable to find it. I visited combat rules, concealment, invisibility, and even the rogues sneak attack.

Comment: Yes, I was almost certain there was a rule to the effect of, "Enemies that aren't aware of you are denied their dexterity bonus to armor class," (it seems to be a pretty common understanding of the rules). I was very surprised to find out how vague the rules on the subject actually are.

Answer (score -1):

Check the invisibility condition in the rule book. It specifically addresses this. It should be something like +2 to attack (assuming they don't have the blindsight or scent abilities) and there is no dex bonus.

Comment: This answer could be improved by quoting (or linking) the rule it references, rather than speaking vaguely about its contents.